# Padding issue with heading for my website

Tags: menu, header, shopify, e-commerce, padding

I do Ecommerce and my website Hous.no uses Shopfiy to code my site where we have a head/menu for our main categories. After adding a heart in our header, it makes two rows when making full width of the website. Our website is Hous.no and "Samling" falls down when opening the website in full width. Does anyone here know if this is a quick fix with padding or if we need to hire someone to fix it?

Tried to inspect element to find the issue but could not find it.